# How to import socket.io from client-side in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The official documentation of `socket.io` has an example of importing and using `socket.io` from client-side like this:

**index.html**

```js
<body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      // Some other code in here...
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Now I'm trying to put my `js` code inside a `main.js` file (beside `index.html` in `public` folder). This is what I do which gives me `Unexpected identifier`:

**main.js**

```js
import io from "../socket.io/socket.io.js"
const socket = io()
// Some other code here...
```

What is the right form of importing `socket.io` in this case?

Comment: If you would like to use the local version of the client-side JS file, you can find it at node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js

Comment: Or npm install socket.io-client and then const { io } = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

Putting this in your **index.html** :

```html
<body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js">
  // some code here...
</body>
```

And putting this in your **main.js** :

```js
var socket = io()
```

Comment: Checked the documentation again. There nothing about `main.js` in it. It's all inside `index.html`.

Comment: @Ehsan Have you tried importing as i mentioned above ?  I checked it on my old project and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways, The simplest one:

You can just use a `socket.io-client` [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io) or serve from the `dist` folder [socket.io-client github repository](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client). It will add the `io` object to `window`. 
Which baically means that `io` will be a global variable that you can use.

You need to add it to your html page using the `script` tag.

and you can use it as:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
</script>
```

**Or,** You can use `webpack` or `browserify` to build the JS file and import THAT in your `index.html`. You can check out examples [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/2.0.3/examples/webpack-build)

**Why `import` doesn't work?**

Because `import` is an ES6 operator. And browsers out of the box don't support that. Heck, even node doesn't support `import` and `export`. That's why you need to transpile(convert) them to ES5 syntaxes so that even browsers can run it. You can check out the trusty [`Babel REPL`](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) and convert Es6 to Es5 yourself to get the feel.

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference when writing `js` inside `html` and when putting `js` in `main.js`. why do we don't import any external library or use `webpack` when writing `js` inside html???

Comment: Edited the answer, added that bit.

Comment: Also you need to put the same script in `main.js` as you put in the html file. Because what you are essentially doing is making another file nothing more than that. Writing JS in html and in client side JS is Exactly the same.

Comment: The thing about ES6 and ES5 kinda makes sense... But where does `src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"` get the module from? I'm not rendering that page, just using node's `sendFile`, so I'm not expecting any ES6 to ES5 conversion!

Comment: Did you open the github repo I added? in the dist folder open the `socket.io.dev.js` and you can see that they are already compiling/transpiling the code for your use. That's why I said either use the pre-compiled versions or compile ur own using webpack/browserify.

Answer (score 1):

if you follow socket.io documentation you should just add these lines

```html
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and make sure to add these lines to your index.js

`const path = require("path"); app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.4/socket.io.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        var socket = io(SOCKET_ENDPOINT);
```